# Somar valor de variáveis com foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma variável que realiza uma função de select, retornando do banco dois valores:

```
$grupo = selectContas();
```

Gostaria de somar esses dois valores e guardar em uma variável, porém, somente o valor do último registro está sendo guardado.

```
<?php
    foreach($grupo as $contas){
        $valortotal = '';
        $valortotal = $valortotal + $contas["valor"];
    }
?>

<?=$valortotal?> (Aqui mostra apenas o último valor do registro)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma: 
Definir a variavel como 0, inicialmente, posterior, você faz a auto soma, usando +=.

```
<?php
    $valortotal = 0;
    foreach($grupo as $contas){
        $valortotal += $contas["valor"];
    }
?>

Total: <?php echo $valortotal; ?>
```

Comment: Deu certo, mas fiquei curiosa porque não consigo desta maneira: $valortotal = $valortotal + $contas["valor"] ? Em tese não seria a mesma coisa?

Comment: Não, porque ai ele estaria somando valores duplicadamente. Se deu certo, por favor, dê um aceite em minha resposta. :) Caso precise, poste!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $valortotal = 0;
> foreach($grupo as $contas){
>
>     if(is_numeric($contas)){
>         $valortotal = $valortotal + intval($contas["valor"]);
>
>     }
> } ?>
> ```